# SQL: Replacing code with sysobjects to one with sys.objects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been playing around with some queries involving Metadata (hopefully, I'm using the correct terminology) and one of the thing I did was to return all the tables created by the current user, using the database.

This is the script:

```
SELECT so.name as [Table], su.name as [User]
FROM sysobjects so
INNER JOIN sysusers su
ON so.uid = su.uid
WHERE xtype = 'U' -- user-defined table
AND su.name=USER_NAME()
```

Then I read that `sysobjects` is in the system only for backward compatibility with SQL Server 2000, and one must use `sys.objects` instead. Well, I tried to change the code, but `sys.objects` doesn't has a column with information related to the user (`sysobjects` has the column `uid`) who created the listed objects.

How can I replace `sysobjects` above by `sys.objects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sys.objects` table. The `principal_id` column contains the value you want:

> **principal_id** - ID of the individual owner, *if different from the
>   schema owner*. By default, schema-contained objects are owned by the
>   schema owner. However, an alternate owner can be specified by using
>   the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement to change ownership.

Source: `sys.objects` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx).

Try this query:

```
SELECT   t.name AS Table_Name
        ,t.principal_id AS Table_Owner_User_Id
        ,s.schema_id
        ,s.name AS Schema_Name
        ,s.principal_id AS Schema_Owner_User_Id
FROM sys.objects t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
        ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.type = 'U'
AND COALESCE(t.principal_id, s.principal_id) = USER_ID()
-- Or, if you must use USER_NAME(), then use the following instead:
--AND USER_NAME(COALESCE(t.principal_id, s.principal_id)) = USER_NAME()
```

Comment: In the column `Table_Owner_User_Id` I get only `NULL`. According to the documentation, and considering that we're only retrieving tables, this means that there are no particular owners (and the ownership went to `dbo` by default). Thanks!!

Comment: Correct. That's why we use the `COALESCE()` function to return the table's `principal_id` or, if it is missing, the schema's `principal_id`.